# Parse JSON without knowing format (can be one of two different objects)

Tags: java, json

I have two concrete objects with a known schema (totally different). Then I get JSON from a client and want to map it into one of this object.

Is it possible to somehow check type before conversion, or I have to try to convert it into each of object and check if parsing was correct?

EDIT:
In example:

```
{"id":"1","name":"oneone"}
```

and second

```
{"age":50,"type":"elephant"}
```

Comment: When they're different a naive approch could be to check for a given string (which is unique per type) and select one of the two types.

Comment: I would suggest add a type variable in the json. Initially, parse it as a map and check the value of type . Accordingly , you can parse it as type A or B.

Comment: Adding new fields are not a option, I don't have control over it

Comment: Can you share the JSONs?

Comment: do these object have associated keys? Or are they like `[{"id":"1","name":"oneone"}, {"age":50,"type":"elephant"}]` in other words, are they contained in an array or in an object

Comment: You don't know which type will be sent until you look at their schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would parse the JSON using GSON or something similar and look for the key that is unique to one of the JSON formats, for instance "age". In reality, you could probably do this as a String as @user743414 mentioned as well.

UPDATE:

Here is some code to reflect what I'm talking about

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
Set<String> keys = jsonObject.keySet();
if(keys.contains("age")){
    //Map to one object
} else {
    //Map to the other object
}
```

Comment: how are you going to let gson parse it if you don't know the type?

Comment: So long as it is well formatted JSON, GSON can parse it.

Comment: what will gson return you, if it doesn't know the object type?

Comment: I added some code to my answer. That's pretty much what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure schema is constant for both JSON’s, then simply take a unique parameter like age in this example and check if it exists in the JSON.

```
If (String.contains(“age”)) {
  //then it’s 2nd JSON
} else {
  //then it’s 1st JSON
}
```

Comment: What if json will have "age" as value?

Comment: @ByeBye then try doing if(String.contains(“\”age\””)) {     This way it only matches with the schema since the values will not have double quotes.